# Bonding of two NIC does not work/go up

Tags: networking, network-interface, interface, bonding

I have a Linux server with two NIC that are connected to a switch (and one NIC for management) and I want to use combine them and use LACP there, but for some unknown reason to me the bonding will just not work/go up.

It also ignores the LACP configuration and goes into round-robin mode.

Huawei switch configuration:

```
interface Eth-Trunk10
description #### Server ####
port link-type trunk
port trunk allow-pass vlan 167
stp disable
mode lacp
load-balance src-dst-mac
```

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp3s0 inet manual

auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet manual
    bond-master bond1

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual
    bond-master bond1

auto bond1
iface bond1 inet manual
    bond-slaves eno1 enp4s0
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-mode 802.3ad
    bond-lacp-rate 1

auto bond1.167
iface bond1.167 inet static
    address x.x.x.x
    netmask 255.255.255.248
    vlan-raw-device bond1

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address  a.a.a.b
    netmask  255.255.255.248
    gateway a.a.a.a
    bridge-ports enp3s0
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
```

/proc/net/bonding/bond1:

```
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: load balancing (round-robin)
MII Status: down
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: enp4s0
MII Status: down
Speed: Unknown
Duplex: Unknown
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:1b:21:3a:6f:f9
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eno1
MII Status: down
Speed: Unknown
Duplex: Unknown
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:1b:21:3a:6f:fb
Slave queue ID: 0
```

Network status:

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2019-09-24 19:33:18 CEST; 13s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 16974 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 16974 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 24 19:33:18 rakete systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Sep 24 19:33:18 rakete ifup[16974]: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ifenslave: 47: echo: echo: I/O error
Sep 24 19:33:18 rakete ifup[16974]: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ifenslave: 47: echo: echo: I/O error
Sep 24 19:33:18 rakete ifup[16974]: Waiting for vmbr0 to get ready (MAXWAIT is 2 seconds).
Sep 24 19:33:18 rakete systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
```

lsmod | grep bond:

```
bonding               159744  0
```

I could not find anything helpful on these error messages. Maybe someone here has some experience with the bonding feature in Linux?

Update, ip lookup:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master mgmt state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether b4:2e:99:3d:68:64 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master bond1 state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:1b:21:3a:6f:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master bond1 state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:1b:21:3a:6f:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: bond1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:1b:21:3a:6f:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: bond1.167@bond1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state LOWERLAYERDOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:1b:21:3a:6f:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: mgmt: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether b4:2e:99:3d:68:64 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> [...] Is bond1.167 ready and a bonding interface ?
> ```

The answer is no, it's a VLAN sub-interface, which hints at the issue: configuration.

Your configuration should define the `bond1` interface, then the `bond1.167` interface which depends on the former. You attempted to short-circuit the configuration, leading to trying to apply bonding settings on a vlan interface, as the log your gave tell.

**UPDATE**: there's an other problem: if *enp4s0* and *eno1*'s definitions reference *bond1* before its definition (reference: with `bond-master bond1`), it appears the configuration scripts from the package *ifenslave* don't cope correctly. After having done a few tests, I can see one can pick one of these work-arounds:

1. remove *auto* from those interfaces. Doing so will bring the actual interfaces up (when *bond1* is configured) but *ifupdown* will still consider them not logically brought up.
2. leaving them at start but with no reference to *bond1* in the interfaces (by removing `bond-master bond1`). Doing so will break the bonding configuration later if one brings a physical interface down with `ifdown` then up again.
3. move their definition after *bond1* definition, keeping `bond-master bond1` (and still keeping `bond-slaves eno1 enp4s0` in *bond1* definition). I couldn't see any drawback left with this method, except the configuration order, so I felt compeled to choose it in the end.

Perhaps [*ifupdown2*](https://packages.debian.org/buster/ifupdown2) can cope with this better than the original [*ifupdown*](https://packages.debian.org/buster/ifupdown):

> It is capable of detecting network interface dependencies

Or even using [*network-manager*](https://packages.debian.org/buster/network-manager) even if perhaps a bit overkill for a server.

Try this configuration instead (change the address):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp3s0 inet manual

auto bond1
iface bond1 inet manual
    bond-slaves eno1 enp4s0
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-mode 802.3ad
    bond-lacp-rate 1

auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet manual
    bond-master bond1

auto eno1    
iface eno1 inet manual
    bond-master bond1

auto bond1.167
iface bond1.167 inet static
    address 192.0.2.2
    netmask 255.255.255.248        
    vlan-raw-device bond1
```

Which then gives here (using an LXC Debian 10 container to test):

```
# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond1 
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
Transmit Hash Policy: layer2 (0)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0
Peer Notification Delay (ms): 0

802.3ad info
LACP rate: fast
Min links: 0
Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable
System priority: 65535
System MAC address: 00:1b:21:3a:6f:fb
Active Aggregator Info:
    Aggregator ID: 1
    Number of ports: 1
    Actor Key: 15
    Partner Key: 1
    Partner Mac Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00

Slave Interface: eno1
MII Status: up
Speed: 10000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:1b:21:3a:6f:fb
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 1
Actor Churn State: monitoring
Partner Churn State: monitoring
Actor Churned Count: 0
Partner Churned Count: 0
details actor lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 00:1b:21:3a:6f:fb
    port key: 15
    port priority: 255
    port number: 1
    port state: 79
details partner lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
    oper key: 1
    port priority: 255
    port number: 1
    port state: 1

Slave Interface: enp4s0
MII Status: up
Speed: 10000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:1b:21:3a:6f:f9
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 2
Actor Churn State: monitoring
Partner Churn State: monitoring
Actor Churned Count: 0
Partner Churned Count: 0
details actor lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 00:1b:21:3a:6f:fb
    port key: 15
    port priority: 255
    port number: 2
    port state: 71
details partner lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
    oper key: 1
    port priority: 255
    port number: 1
    port state: 1

# cat /proc/net/vlan/bond1.167 
bond1.167  VID: 167  REORDER_HDR: 1  dev->priv_flags: 1021
         total frames received            0
          total bytes received            0
      Broadcast/Multicast Rcvd            0

      total frames transmitted           12
       total bytes transmitted          976
Device: bond1
INGRESS priority mappings: 0:0  1:0  2:0  3:0  4:0  5:0  6:0 7:0
 EGRESS priority mappings:
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am just about to try this out, as soon as I am having remote access to the box again.

Comment: You were right, the cascading/shortcut was wrong and bond1 is now up and shown as active LACP connection. One question though: bond1.167 still does not appear as an interface, when using the "ip a" or "ping -I bond1.167 8.8.8.8" commands. It says, this interface does not exist. Do I have to create another interface/bridge like for example "auto vmbr0" and then use "bridge-ports bond1.167" and also put the IP address there?

Comment: I added the ip lookup output.

Comment: From what you added: both enp4s0 and eno1 interfaces are down, even if I don't know why. They are either down from the network scripts, in such case running `ifup enp4s0; ifup eno1` will bring them up, or down from the low level layer (while the configuration scripts "think" they ran), in such case `ip link set enp4s0 up; ip link set eno1 up` will work. Does it stay not working after a reboot?

Comment: Alright, this did something (not the reboot, but the ip link set ... commands). I will alter the initial post newer information.

Comment: What I do not understand: eno1 and enp4s0 are just not starting by themselves after a reboot. I always have to do this: ip link set enp4s0 up ; ip link set eno1 up.

Comment: I could reproduce the issue, and probably guessed what causes it. I updated my answer (and the configuration to use instead) accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. I will test this later on, too, but I have a hunch, you are quite right about that.